# Why was try...catch was recommended to me here?

Tags: javascript, try-catch, ecmascript-5

I'm modding a game which uses JavaScript for its UI. All its scenes look something like the following:

```js
var model;
var handlers = {};

$(document).ready(function()
{
    // code
    loadSceneMods('scene_name')
    // more code
});
```

The function called does the following:

```js
function loadSceneMods(scene) {
    
    if (_.has(scene_mod_list, scene)){
        debuglog("loadSceneMods for scene:" + scene) // outputs to console
        loadMods(scene_mod_list[scene]);
    }else{
        debuglog("loadSceneMods no mods for scene: " + scene) // outputs to console
    }
}

function loadMods(list) {
    var start = Date.now();
    var i;
    var mod;
    var type;

    var js = /[.]js$/;
    var css = /[.]css$/;

    if (api.Panel.pageName === 'game')
        init_browser();

    console.log("loadMods...");
    for ( i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        mod = list[i];

        console.log(encode(mod));

        if (mod.match(js))
            loadScript(mod);

        if (mod.match(css))
            loadCSS(mod);
    }
    console.log("loadMods done. mods loaded in " + (Date.now() - start)/1000 + " seconds" );
}
```

When I was learning JavaScript I was told by someone who is a programmer by day how I should be structuring my code as best practice. However, I have since lost contact and never asked why this structure is what they said I should use:

```js
var modSceneNameLoaded;

if (!modSceneNameLoaded) {
  modSceneNameLoaded = true;

  function modSceneName() {
    try {
      // code
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
      console.error(JSON.stringify(e));
    }
  }
  modSceneName();
}
```

My understanding of this block is that it achieves the following:

1. It will prevent the code being loaded more than once by the game. This seems like sound defensive code, if perhaps a bit excessive.
2. It contains all the mod's logic in its own function to avoid variable clashes and polluting the global namespace. This appears essential.
3. That it will catch any errors. I don't really understand if this is necessary, or how it differs from normal error output in its current form, even after reading up on try...catch. The only bit I get is that `JSON.stringify(e)` allows me to see the full output of an error.

As my code has grown the nesting this introduces is more of an issue. However, I'm struggling to make sound decisions around what trade-offs are acceptable without first fully understanding why they advised this structure.

**My questions are:**

1. Are my understandings 1 & 2 correct?
2. Is a try...catch really necessary or adding value here?

Comment: *the function called does the following:* You neglected to explain what it does. You also neglected to include the code inside `modScene()`, so i don't know if we can say whether it prevents it from loading multiple times.  Regardless, if you catch an error, you can control how it's handled with [graceful degradation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Graceful_degradation).

Comment: You could wrap `modSceneName();` with `try`/`catch` instead of `// code`. _"Is a try...catch really necessary or adding value here?"_ `try`/`catch` should never be necessary. Don't use error handling for logic. It adds value if the containing code can throw. _"Are my understandings 1 & 2 correct?"_ Yes.

Comment: @mykaf _"i don't know if we can say whether it prevents it from loading multiple times"_ You can say it by reading the third code snippet: `if (!modSceneNameLoaded) { modSceneNameLoaded = true;`

Comment: (1) yes, but it uses a global variable to do so - just add it as a property to the function `function modSceneName() { if (modSceneName.loaded) return; ...`

Comment: (2) there are better options, such as namespaces or modules

Comment: (3) 20+ years ago this was the only way to catch errors, but for some time there's been an `error` event on the window: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/error_event - so to answer (3) - no, use a *global* error handler.  *However* depending on how your "mod" works and how the engine that uses works, it could be that you can't use (eg) global error handler.    And it may be that the engine auto calls the mod (as a plugin) so can't wrap the call either - in which case, yes - but only around the outer-most call, not around every call (implied with "as my code grows")

Comment: (2) or an IIFE as it appears to be a one-off.  And use `let` instead of `var` to ensure there's no scope-creep